# Consecutive occurrence in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the above data frame containing different measurements. I would like to identify consecutive measurements (with the length size of more or equal with 6) of `w` taken at a time `t`. For example, in the case of `id 1` from `t3:t8` there are `6` consecutive `w` measures recorded.

I would like to save the results into 2 data frames:

```
df1: At least 6 consecutive measurements of w (per id) before the first occurrence of w;
df2: From timing of the last occurrence of w (per id) there are less than 6 consecutive measurements of w;
```

The format of my dataset with and without consecutive w occurrences:

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
  1  s  s  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w #7 occ. of w after t3
  2  s  w  w  w  e  w  w  w  w  w  #no 6 consecutive w occurance
  3  w  w  w  w  w  w  s  s  s  r #6 occ. of w before t6
  4  e  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w #9 occ. of w after t1
  5  w  w  w  w  w  w  r  w  w  w #6 occ. of w before t7
  6  w  s  w  r  w  r  w  w  s  w #no 6 consecutive w occurance
```

Output:

```
Before w:

id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 10
3                  w  s  s  s  r
5                  w  r  
   
After w:

id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 10
1   s  s  w
4   e  w
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), t1=c("s","s","w","e","w","w"), t2=c("s","w","w","w","w","s"),t3 = c("w","w","w","w","w","w"),
                        t4 = c("w","w","w","w","w","r"), t5 = c("w","e","w","w","w","w"), t6 = c("w","w","w","w","w","r"),
                       t7= c("w","w","s","w","r","w"), t8 = c("w","w","s","w","w","w"), t9=c("e","w","s","w","w","s"), t10=c("w","w","r","w","w","w")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Codes:

`Before` (Not working for at least 6 consecutive time steps):

```
df1 <- df
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, seq_along(x) > match('w', x), '')))
df1<-df1[rowSums(df1 == 'w')!=0,  ,drop = FALSE]
```

`After` (Not working for at least 6 consecutive time steps):

```
df2 <- df
df2[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, seq_along(x) <= match('w', x), '')))

df2 <- df2[c(TRUE, colSums(df2[-2] != '') > 0)]
df2<-df2[rowSums(df2 == 'w')!=0,  ,drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very smart and more experimental, but you could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- pivot_longer(df, -id) %>%
  group_by(id, idx = rep(1:length(rle(value)$length), times = rle(value)$length)) %>%
  filter(any(cumsum(value == 'w') == 6 & value == 'w') | value != 'w') %>%
  group_by(id) %>% select(-idx) %>%
  filter(any(value == 'w')) %>%
  mutate(w_consec = cumsum(value == 'w'),
         group = case_when(
           any(value != 'w' & w_consec == 0) ~ 'After',
           any(value != 'w' & w_consec == 6) ~ 'Before')) %>%
  filter(
    if (any(group == 'After')) (value == 'w' & w_consec == 1) | (value != 'w' & w_consec == 0)
    else w_consec == 6
    ) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c('id', 'group'), names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

With grouping by `idx` variable in the second step, we ensure that we only keep occurrences of `w` which belong to a consecutive set of 6 repeats. Otherwise we could run into an issue where with example sequence `wwwwwwebww`, we would lose `eb` information as all `w` would be included in next steps, thus ending with a single `w`. `rle` function is used in this case to assign the same value to all consecutive occurrences of any character (the way it is used above has the same behaviour as `data.table::rleid` function, you can check help page for the latter to get more context).

After that, you can use `split`:

```
split(df, df$group)
```

Output:

```
$After
# A tibble: 2 x 10
# Groups:   id [2]
     id group t1    t2    t3    t6    t7    t8    t9    t10  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 After s     s     w     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
2     4 After e     w     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   

$Before
# A tibble: 2 x 10
# Groups:   id [2]
     id group  t1    t2    t3    t6    t7    t8    t9    t10  
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     3 Before NA    NA    NA    w     s     s     s     r    
2     5 Before NA    NA    NA    w     r     NA    NA    NA
```

If you want to include it within your environment as separate data frames:

```
list2env(
  split(df, df$group), .GlobalEnv
)
```

Comment: many thanks when you have time could you please add some comments  around repx function and idx. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably easier to solve with regex. Specifically, `(^|[^w]+)w(?=w{6})` and `(?<=([^w]|^)(w{5}))w([^w]+|$)`.

Combine all columns into a single string.

```
library("tidyverse")

df_original <- read_table("
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
  1  s  s  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w
  2  s  w  w  w  e  w  w  w  w  w
  3  w  w  w  w  w  w  s  s  s  r
  4  e  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w
  5  w  w  w  w  w  w  r  w  w  w
  6  w  s  w  r  w  r  w  w  s  w
")

df <- df_original %>% unite(col = "combined", -id, sep = "") 
df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>      id combined  
#>   <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1     1 sswwwwwwww
#> 2     2 swwwewwwww
#> 3     3 wwwwwwsssr
#> 4     4 ewwwwwwwww
#> 5     5 wwwwwwrwww
#> 6     6 wswrwrwwsw
```

`str_locate` can be used to find the start and end points of interest using regex.

- `(^|[^w]+)w(?=w{6})` means find `non-w` followed by `w` followed by 6 `w`s.
- `(?<=([^w]|^)(w{5}))w([^w]+|$)` means find `non-w` followed by 5 `w`s followed by `w` followed by `non-w`.

See `?stringi::about_search_regex` for syntax details.

```
df1 <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(end_points = str_locate(combined, "(^|[^w]+)w(?=w{6})"))
df1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      id combined   end_points[,"start"] [,"end"]
#>   <dbl> <chr>                     <int>    <int>
#> 1     1 sswwwwwwww                    1        3
#> 2     2 swwwewwwww                   NA       NA
#> 3     3 wwwwwwsssr                   NA       NA
#> 4     4 ewwwwwwwww                    1        2
#> 5     5 wwwwwwrwww                   NA       NA
#> 6     6 wswrwrwwsw                   NA       NA

df2 <-
  df %>%
  mutate(end_points = str_locate(combined, "(?<=([^w]|^)(w{5}))w([^w]+|$)"))
df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      id combined   end_points[,"start"] [,"end"]
#>   <dbl> <chr>                     <int>    <int>
#> 1     1 sswwwwwwww                   NA       NA
#> 2     2 swwwewwwww                   NA       NA
#> 3     3 wwwwwwsssr                    6       10
#> 4     4 ewwwwwwwww                   NA       NA
#> 5     5 wwwwwwrwww                    6        7
#> 6     6 wswrwrwwsw                   NA       NA
```

To turn the end points into a masked string, we can use `mask_string`.

```
mask_string <- function(string, start, end) {
  result <- str_pad("", nchar(string))
  str_sub(result, start, end) <- str_sub(string, start, end)
  result
}

df1 <-
  df1 %>%
  mutate(masked = mask_string(combined, end_points[, "start"], end_points[, "end"]))
df1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id combined   end_points[,"start"] [,"end"] masked      
#>   <dbl> <chr>                     <int>    <int> <chr>       
#> 1     1 sswwwwwwww                    1        3 "ssw       "
#> 2     2 swwwewwwww                   NA       NA  NA         
#> 3     3 wwwwwwsssr                   NA       NA  NA         
#> 4     4 ewwwwwwwww                    1        2 "ew        "
#> 5     5 wwwwwwrwww                   NA       NA  NA         
#> 6     6 wswrwrwwsw                   NA       NA  NA      

df2 <-
  df2 %>%
  mutate(masked = mask_string(combined, end_points[, "start"], end_points[, "end"]))
df2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id combined   end_points[,"start"] [,"end"] masked      
#>   <dbl> <chr>                     <int>    <int> <chr>       
#> 1     1 sswwwwwwww                   NA       NA  NA         
#> 2     2 swwwewwwww                   NA       NA  NA         
#> 3     3 wwwwwwsssr                    6       10 "     wsssr"
#> 4     4 ewwwwwwwww                   NA       NA  NA         
#> 5     5 wwwwwwrwww                    6        7 "     wr   "
#> 6     6 wswrwrwwsw                   NA       NA  NA
```

Then, this can be mapped backed to the columns `t1`, `t2` etc like this.

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(masked)) %>%
  separate(masked, c("blank", names(df_original)[-1]), "") %>%
  select(id, starts_with("t"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>      id t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    t7    t8    t9    t10  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 s     s     "w"   " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   " "  
#> 2     4 e     w     " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   " "  


df2 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(masked)) %>%
  separate(masked, c("blank", names(df_original)[-1]), "") %>%
  select(id, starts_with("t"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>      id t1    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6    t7    t8    t9    t10  
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     3 " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   w     s     "s"   "s"   "r"  
#> 2     5 " "   " "   " "   " "   " "   w     r     " "   " "   " "
```