# Identify start and end time of a value per id in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

This relates to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186225/consecutive-occurrence-in-a-data-frame) on identifying the occurrence of a value in a data frame per id. This time I am trying to identify consecutive measurements per id with a length of 4 or more.

Ex.

Below an example of the consecutive occurrence of w with the length of 4

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
 1  s  s  w  w  w  w
```

For the same id  an example of the consecutive occurrence of w with the length of 4 as well 4 non-w occurrences after the last w

```
  id   t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
   1    w  w  w  w  r  s  s  s
```

I would like to save this in a df as:

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
  1  s  s  w        w  r  s  s  s
```

The format of my dataset with and without consecutive w occurrences:

```
    id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
    1  s  s  w  w  w  w  r  s  s  s #after t2 value there are 4 occ. of w and after t6 (last one) there are 4 non-w occ.      
    2  s  w  w  w  e  w  w  s  t  v  #no 4 consecutive w occurrence and no 4 non-w occurrence after t7
    3  w  w  w  w  w  d  s  s  s  r #5 occ. of w after t5
    4  e  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w #9 occ. of w after t1
    5  w  e  w  w  w  w  r  r  r  r #4 occ. of w after t2 and 4 occ. of non-w after t6
    6  w  s  w  r  w  r  w  w  s  w #no 4 consecutive w occurance
```

Output:

```
id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
1   s  s  w       w  r  s  s  s
3              w  d  s  s  s  r 
4   e  w
5                 w  r  r   r  r
```

How can I split this format to have to 2 df's one with the start and the one with the end values?

Ex.

```
df1:

  id t1 t2 t3 
   1  s  s  w
```

as well the other start cases for id2, id3...

```
df2:

id   t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
1     w  r  s  s  s
```

as well the other end cases for id2, id3...

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), t1=c("s","s","w","e","w","w"), t2=c("s","w","w","w","e","s"),t3 = c("w","w","w","w","w","w"),
                        t4 = c("w","w","w","w","w","r"), t5 = c("w","e","w","w","w","w"), t6 = c("w","w","d","w","w","r"),
                       t7= c("r","w","s","w","r","w"), t8 = c("s","s","s","w","r","w"), t9=c("s","t","s","w","r","s"), t10=c("s","v","r","w","r","w")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Codes that identify the start and endpoints based on w:

`Start` (Not working consecutive time steps):

```
df1 <- df
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, seq_along(x) > match('w', x), '')))
df1<-df1[rowSums(df1 == 'w')!=0,  ,drop = FALSE]
```

`End` (Not working for consecutive time steps):

```
df2 <- df
df2[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, seq_along(x) <= match('w', x), '')))

df2 <- df2[c(TRUE, colSums(df2[-2] != '') > 0)]
df2<-df2[rowSums(df2 == 'w')!=0,  ,drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Row 5 starts with w,e,w but your output drops that, why?

Comment: Your second part of this question is asking for something that **cannot** be a dataframe, since the number of columns in each ID is not likely to be the same.

Comment: ... and, why do you reference "4 consecutive" in the beginning of the question and "6" at the end?

Comment: @r2evans thank you for your time. The reason is that w at t1 is not part of a 4 or more consecutive series. So, after w at t1 at t2 there is a non-w value.

Comment: @r2evans true, sorry updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 1 of your multi-part question, here's a solution:

```r
myfunc <- function(s, len = 4, what = "w") {
  r <- rle(s)
  rlen <- length(r$values)
  for (ind in rev(seq_len(rlen))) {
    if (r$values[ind] != what) next
    if (r$lengths[ind] < len) next
    r$values <- c(
      if (ind > 1) r$values[1:(ind - 1L)],
      r$values[ind], "", r$values[ind],
      if (ind < rlen) r$values[(ind + 1L):rlen])
    r$lengths <- c(
      if (ind > 1) r$lengths[1:(ind - 1L)],
      1L, r$lengths[ind] - 2L, 1L,
      if (ind < rlen) r$lengths[(ind + 1L):rlen])
  }
  rlen <- length(r$values)
  if (r$lengths[1] == 1L && r$values[1] == what &&
        rlen > 1 && r$values[2] == "") {
    r$values[1] <- ""
  }
  if (r$lengths[rlen] == 1 && r$values[rlen] == what &&
        rlen > 1 && r$values[rlen-1] == "") {
    r$values[rlen] <- ""
  }
  inverse.rle(r)
}
```

Apply this to each row (sans `id`):

```r
out <- cbind(df[,1,drop=F], t(apply(df[,-1], 1, myfunc)))
colnames(out)[-1] <- colnames(df)[-1]
out
#   id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
# 1  1  s  s  w        w  r  s  s   s
# 2  2  s  w  w  w  e  w  w  s  t   v
# 3  3              w  d  s  s  s   r
# 4  4  e  w                         
# 5  5  w  e  w        w  r  r  r   r
# 6  6  w  s  w  r  w  r  w  w  s   w
```

Compare with your expected output:

```
id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
1   s  s  w       w  r  s  s  s
3              w  d  s  s  s  r 
4   e  w
5                 w  r  r  r  r
```

Difference:

- my row 5 keeps the leading `w e w`, since there was no rule in your conditions that would suggest it needs to be reduced.

---

Let's dive into one row of data to find out what's going on.

```r
unlist(df[5,-1])
#  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9 t10 
# "w" "e" "w" "w" "w" "w" "r" "r" "r" "r" 

myfunc( unlist(df[5,-1]) )

  r <- rle(s)
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: Named int [1:4] 1 1 4 4
#   values : Named chr [1:4] "w" "e" "w" "r"
```

(I've removed R's `attr` attributes here for brevity.) This says that there are four distinct sequences. First comes 1 "w", then 1 "e", then 4 "w", then 4 "r". We're now going to iterate over each of them and, if they meet our constraints (match `what` length `len`), then we replace the `values` and `lengths`.

But we need to do it backwards, so that the next `ind` value (iterating over the indices of each vector) has not shifted. Ergo, `rev(...)` within the `for` loop.

```r
  rlen <- length(r$values)

ind <- 4 # look at the last value/length first
    if (r$values[ind] != what) next

ind <- 3
    if (r$values[ind] != what) next # nope, keep going
    if (r$lengths[ind] < len) next  # nope, keep going
```

At this point, since we passed both `if` statements, we now need to replace the `$values` and `$lengths` at `[ind]`:

- the old value of `r$values[3]` (`"w"`) needs to be replaced with `c("w", "", "w")` to indicate the first value, all middle values, and the last value;
- the old length of `r$lengths[3]` (4 here) needs to be replaced with `c(1, 4-2, 1)`, where the first 1 corresponds to the new values first `"w"`; the `4-2` corresponds to the new `""`; and the second `1` is for the second `"w"` in the replaced vector

The `if (...)` within the new vectors are so that we deal correctly with `ind==1` or `ind==rlen`, where `[1-1]` and `[rlen+1]` will not do what we want.

Okay, let's step out of the loop, we've replaced the values. THe current status of `r` is:

```r
r
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: Named int [1:6] 1 1 1 2 1 4
#   values : Named chr [1:6] "w" "e" "w" "" "w" "r"
```

(`attr` removed.) Notice the changes: 1 w, 1 e, 1 w, 2 "", 1 w, 4 r.

Let's continue, in order to replace a first or last `"w"`:

```r
  rlen <- length(r$values) # because it may have changed
  if (r$lengths[1] == 1L && r$values[1] == what &&
        rlen > 1 && r$values[2] == "") {
    r$values[1] <- ""
  }
```

Normally, if we started with 4 or more `"w"`, then `t1` would be `"w"`, `t2` would be `""`, etc. In your expected output, you want this leading `"w"` removed, so the 4-part `if` clause is to see if this condition exists, and remove it accordingly. (The fact that `r$values[1:2]` are now the same does not matter.)

Similar for the end of the vector.

In this case, it did not meet either condition, so `r` is unchanged from post-`for`-loop.

Lastly, we call `inverse.rle` which takes the numbers and counts and converts back into the vector.

```r
  inverse.rle(r)
#  [1] "w" "e" "w" ""  ""  "w" "r" "r" "r" "r"

### perfectly equivalent to
rep(r$values, times = r$lengths)
#  t1  t2  t6          t6 t10 t10 t10 t10 
# "w" "e" "w"  ""  "" "w" "r" "r" "r" "r"
```

(Actually, `inverse.rle` *uses* `rep.int`, which is a little faster than `rep` but with fewer features.)

Comment: when you have time could you please explain your approach and code. thanks