# Handle consecutive occurance if there is empty space

Tags: r, dataframe

This question relates to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186225/consecutive-occurrence-in-a-data-frame/64186639#64186639) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189020/identify-start-and-end-time-of-a-value-per-id-in-a-data-frame) on identifying the occurrence of a value in a data frame per id.

This time I am trying to identify non-consecutive measurements per id with a length of 3 or more. These non-w measurements occur after consecutive occurrences of w (consecutive occurrence length size at least 3). I don't know how to handle empty spaces. Even though if I replace with `na's` still not working.

```
      id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
      1           w  w  w  r  s  r # empty space t1:t3; 3 consecutive occ. of w and 3 non-consec. occ. after the last w at t6
      2        w  w  e  w  w  w  w # empty space t1:t2; 4 consec. occ. of w start at t6 but no non-w occ. after the last w 
      3  w  w  w  w  w  w  s  s  s # no empty space; 6 consec. w occ.; 3 non-w occ. start at t7
      4     w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w # t1 empty space; 8 consec. w occ. but no non-w occ. after the last w
      5  w  w  w  w  w  w  r  s  w # no empty space; consec w occ. till t6; 2 non-w occ. but not after the last occ. of w and not 3 times
      6     s  w  r  w  r  w  w  s # no empty space; 2 consec. occ. of w and 1 non-w occ. after the last w.
```

Ex.

Below an example of the consecutive occurrence of `w` with the length of `3`. From `t1:t3` there are empty spaces; from `t4:t6` there are `3` consecutive occurrences of w and from `t7:t9` there are 3 non-w occurrences (doesn't matter if they are consecutive or not).

```
  id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
   1           w  w  w  r  s  r
```

I would like to save the non-w occurrences in a `df` as:

```
 id  t6  t7 t8 t9 
  1   w  r  s  r
```

What I don't know:

- How to identify the last position of consecutive occurrence of `w` length at least 3

Ex. How can I find out if in the last `w` position - that is `t6`

```
   id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
   1           w  w  w  r  s  r
```

- How can I find out if after the last `w` position - that is `t6` there at least `3` consecutive `non-w` occurrences?

Ex. How can I find out if after the last `w` position - that is `t6` at t7:t9 there is non-w occurrence.

```
   id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
   1           w  w  w  r  s  r
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), t1=c("","","w","","w","", "w"), t2=c("","","w","w","w","s", "w"),t3 = c("","w","w","w","w","w", "w"),
                    t4 = c("w","w","w","w","w","r", "w"), t5 = c("w","e","w","w","w","w", "r"), t6 = c("w","w","w","w","w","r", "s"),
                    t7 = c("r","w","s","w","r","w", "t"), t8 = c("r","w","s","w","s","w", "v"), t9=c("r","w","s","w","w","s"), "z"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df
```

Output `df`:

```
 id  t6 t7 t8 t9
  1  w  r  s  r 
  3  w  s  s  s
```

There is also a special case when t does not start at the same time for example from the below `df` at `id 7` the last w occurrence at `t4` and not at `t6` as in other case.

```
  id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
  1           w  w  w  r  r  r
  2        w  w  e  w  w  w  w
  3  w  w  w  w  w  w  s  s  s
  4     w  w  w  w  w  w  w  w
  5  w  w  w  w  w  w  r  s  w
  6     s  w  r  w  r  w  w  z
  7  w  w  w  w  r  s  t  v  s
```

This output would be more complex. Wouldn't be easier to remove the w's if(consec. occ.lenght at least 3) and to keep the second part of the sequence if occ.lenght at least 3?

```
 id   t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
   1         w  r  s  r 
   3         w  s  s  s
   7  w   r  s  t  v  s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` row-wise :

```
mat <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {
  #rle to find consecutive occurrence of w
  a1 <- rle(x == 'w')
  #Find the position of last 'w' in rle output
  a2 <- max(which(a1$values))
  #Find the position of last 'w' in x
  a3 <- sum(a1$lengths[1:a2])
  #If the consecutive occurrence of last w is greater than equal to 3 and 
  #If there are more than 3 values after the last w
  if(a1$length[a2] >= 3 & length(x) >=  a3 + 3)
    #Keep only the values after the last w
    x[a3:length(x)]
})
#Get length of elements in each list
n <- lengths(mat)
#Get max n meaning number of columns in final dataframe
m <- max(n)
#Append NA's to shorter elements to make the length equal
new_mat <- t(sapply(mat[n > 0], function(x) c(rep(NA, m - length(x)), x)))
#Create a new dataframe
data.frame(id = df$id[n > 0], new_mat)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:7, t1 = c("", "", "w", "", "w", "", "w"
), t2 = c("", "", "w", "w", "w", "s", "w"), t3 = c("", "w", "w", 
"w", "w", "w", "w"), t4 = c("w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "r", "w"
), t5 = c("w", "e", "w", "w", "w", "w", "r"), t6 = c("w", "w", 
"w", "w", "w", "r", "s"), t7 = c("r", "w", "s", "w", "r", "w", 
"t"), t8 = c("r", "w", "s", "w", "s", "w", "v"), t9 = c("r", 
"w", "s", "w", "w", "z", "s")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-7L))
```

Comment: many thanks when you have time I made an update as I observed that in some case the start time steps do not match eg. some series start at t1 others at t3. I included an example. thanks

Comment: @user11418708 I updated the answer for the cases where the lengths are not equal.